# All of .... use or omit of?

Tags: word-choice, phrases, expressions

While writing a sentence , I used **all of my books**  , I got stuck with the usage of "of".

Which of the two shall I write:

> all of my books

vs

> all my books

Comment: One or the other. They're both just fine and there's no difference between them. This is the patter for _all_. For _each_, however, you **can't** omit the _of_: _Each of my books is marked_ is OK, but not  *_Each my books is marked_. With _every_, there's a different pattern: _Every book is marked_ is OK, but not *_Every of my book(s)_ or _Every my book(s)_, though _Every one of my books_ is fine. **Don't** think of markers like auxiliary verbs, particles, articles, quantifiers, complementizers, or prepositions as being separate from the constructions they're in. They're part of the machinery.

Answer (score 0):

> When a **noun** is preceded by an adjective or by the, it’s leaner and cleaner to drop the of in **all of**:

- all my books
- all the lessons of history.

> When a **pronoun** is involved, the of is essential, as in phrases like:

- all of it
- all of us

When a **possessive noun** is preceded by a or an,the 'of' is required:

- all of a book’s wisdom
- all of history’s lessons